# Spark Streaming With Kafka (Direct approach) only consumes messages as long as producer is running

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

So, I have a producer that reads a log file from hdfs and then sends line by line to kafka. At the other end I am consuming the messages on SparkStreaming using the [API kafkaUtils](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers). My goal is to perform real-time analysis on the logs. The problem is that the consumer only gets the messages as long as the producer is running. When the producer is done sending (i.e. successfully comes outta the while loop in the producer code below), the reciever stops showing me messages eventhough it has not consumed everything. 
However if I used the out-of-the-box simple consumer of Kafka, it shows me all the messages whenever I run the script.

```
/usr/lib/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic2 --from-beginning
```

I have a topic called *topic2* whose configuration looks like this:

```
Topic:topic2    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
Topic: topic2   Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0,1
```

The brokers are on localhost:9092 (id: 0), localhost:9093 (id:1) and localhost:9094 (id:2)

Also, I'm running the whole thing on Eclipse Luna on Cloudera Quickstart VM (if it makes a difference)

SparkConsumer.java

```
public class SparkConsumer {

private static Function2<Long, Long, Long> SUM_REDUCER = (a, b) -> a + b;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: JavaDirectKafkaWordCount <brokers> <topics>\n" +
          "  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers\n" +
          "  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from\n\n");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    String brokers = args[0]; //This recieves localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094
    String topics = args[1]; //This recieves *topic2*

    SparkConf sparkConf = new  SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("SparkConsumer").set("spark.driver.host", "localhost");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
   //JavaSQLContext sqlContext = new JavaSQLContext(sc);

    // Create a StreamingContext with a 1 second batch size
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(1)); 

    Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(",")));
    Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "largest");
    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        jssc,
        String.class,
        String.class,
        StringDecoder.class,
        StringDecoder.class,
        kafkaParams,
        topicsSet
    );

    // Get the lines, split them into words, count the words and print
    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
      @Override
      public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
        return tuple2._2();
      }
    });

    lines.print(); 
    //Here's where I plan to do the procesing using Spark when I'm done with this basic thing.
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();}}
```

HdfsProducer.java

```
public class HdfsProducer {
public static void readFromHdfs(Producer<String, String> producer, String topicName) {

    try{
        //1. Get the instance of Configuration
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        //2. URI of the file to be read
        URI uri = new URI("hdfs://0.0.0.0:8022/data/apache-access-log.txt");
        //3. Get the instance of the HDFS 
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(uri, configuration);
        Path pt = new Path(uri);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hdfs.open(pt)));
        String line;
        //System.out.println("Hello World");
        //System.out.println("\n Successfully read hadoop file");
        line=br.readLine();
        int count = 0;
        //while (line != null && count < 5){
        while (line != null){
            System.out.println("Sending batch" + count);
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, new String(line)));
            line=br.readLine();
            count = count+1;
        }

        producer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public static Producer<String, String> getProducer(String topicName)throws Exception{

    // create instance for properties to access producer configs   
            Properties props = new Properties();

            //Assign localhost id
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9093");

            //Set acknowledgements for producer requests.      
            props.put("acks", "all");

            //If the request fails, the producer can automatically retry,
            props.put("retries", 0);

            //Specify buffer size in config
            props.put("batch.size", 16384);

            //Reduce the no of requests less than 0   
            props.put("linger.ms", 5);

            //The buffer.memory controls the total amount of memory available to the producer for buffering.   
            props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);

            props.put("key.serializer", 
                    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

            props.put("value.serializer", 
                    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

            Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer
                    <String, String>(props);

            return producer;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


    // Check arguments length value
    if(args.length == 0){
        System.out.println("Enter topic name");
        return;
    }

    //Assign topicName to string variable
    String topicName = args[0].toString(); //This receives *topic2*

    //Get a producer and then use it to read the logs from HDFS
    readFromHdfs(getProducer(topicName), topicName);


}}
```

Also, I have tried running this with auto.offset.reset=smallest. In this case, I get few messages which I had sent at the very beginning and then I do not get anything. 
The consumer should be seeing all the messages when the offset is smallest regardless of when the messages were sent right? (assuming that all the messages are persisting on the brokers because the simple consumer works fine). I did read the documentation for kafka, kafka intergration with spark, spark-streaming but wasnt able to proceed. Being new to Java doesnt help either:) I'd really appreciate if somebody could point out to what I'm missing here.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe that's a bit off the point, but why do you need kafka at all in this use case? Why not just stream the files from hdfs directly, for example as described here:
http://statrgy.com/2015/06/04/spark-streaming-simple-example-streaming-data-from-hdfs/

Comment: There is a requirement to use Kafka (possibly to leverage pub-sub model in future for scaling?) but I appreciate your input. And I'm using Spark because I'm familiar with the framework albeit in Python. Also, I figured it out problem: There was none! The topic had way too many messages and I did not see any on console because spark had launced map jobs for them which was taking some time. Can't believe I wasted half a day on this!